# Why does Java function return 1 when given ""

Tags: java

I am new to Java. The purpose of the function is to get a word's vowel count. But when given `""` as input it returns `1` instead of `0`.

Please explain like i am five why this is happening.

```
public static int getCount(String str) {
        String vowels = "aeiou";
        int answer = 0;

        String strArray[] = str.split("");

        for(String chr : strArray) {
            if ((vowels.contains(chr)) & (chr != "")) {
                answer += 1;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

I fixed the code by adding `if ((vowels.contains(chr)) & (chr != ""))`
But this feels ugly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java for an explanation of why `chr != ""` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"".split("")` returns `{""}`. If you want to go over the characters, use one of these:

```java
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (vowels.indexOf(c) != -1) { ... }
}
```

```java
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (vowels.indexOf(c) != -1) { ... }
}
```

I prefer the second, it doesn't create a copy of the string.

Comment: Nit pick. I'd prefer `char c = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you're right of course, otherwise `vowels` would need to include `AEIOU` as well.